# Unset DependencyProperty throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, exception, windows-store-apps, dependency-properties

I am working on a Windows Store App. A custom class uses a DependencyProperty of an enum type. When I try to access this property without having set it before the app crashes with an NullReferenceException. The same code runs without any problem on Windows Phone.

```
public enum ItemDisplayType {
    None,
    Detail,
    Any,
}

public class CustomClass : UserControl {
    public CustomClass () {
        // No crash when DisplayType is set
        // DisplayType = ItemDisplayType.Any;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayType", typeof(ItemDisplayType), typeof(CustomClass), null);
    public ItemDisplayType DisplayType{
        get { return (ItemDisplayType)GetValue(DisplayTypeProperty); }
        set {
            SetValue(DisplayTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand what's the problem here. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh920267.aspx) an unset DependencyProperty should return the default value:

> If a default value is not specified, the default value for a dependency property is null for a reference type, or the default of the type for a value type or language primitive (for example, 0 for an integer or an empty string for a string).

So what it is the problem here? Why does this code run on Windows Phone and not on Windows Store Apps?

Answer (score 0):

You have set the default value to `null` at the end of your `DependencyProperty` declaration. Set it to `ItemDisplayType.None`. You may be able to use `default(ItemDisplayType)`, but I'm not sure if that will work.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayType", typeof(ItemDisplayType), typeof(CustomClass), ItemDisplayType.None);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right of course. But this was just an error when writing the example code here. The real code is correct and still shows the described problem. I have fixed the code in my question.